# Assign unique serial from a list in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to assign a unique serial on Google sheets from a list of serials to an order made from google forms but I couldn't do it, could someone help me?

order type
[image: order type]

list of serials
[image: list of serials]

Comment: please see [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is the way to transform your first sheet to desired output? How to assign that serials? The question needs a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

With this script:

```js
function assignOrders() {
  // Define Sheets
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let serialSh = ss.getSheetByName("serials"); // Change right to sheet name
  let orderSh = ss.getSheetByName("orders"); // Change right to sheet name

  // Define Ranges and Data
  let serialRange = serialSh.getDataRange();
  let serialData = serialRange.getValues();
  let orderRange = orderSh.getDataRange();
  let orderData = orderRange.getValues();

  // Take out header rows
  let serialHeaders = serialData.shift();
  let orderHeaders = orderData.shift();

  // Go through each order row
  orderData.forEach((row) => {
    // If order row doesn't have laptop serial
    if (row[3] == "") {
      // Go through each laptop
      for (let i = 0; i < serialData.length; i++)
        // If it is DISPONIBLE and the MODELO is the same assign it and break
        if (serialData[i][4] == "DISPONIBLE" && serialData[i][2] == row[1]) {
          row[3] = serialData[i][3];
          serialData[i][4] = "ASIGNADO";
          break;
        }
    }
  });

  // Update the ranges with the assignments
  orderRange
    .offset(1, 0, orderData.length, orderData[0].length)
    .setValues(orderData);
  serialRange
    .offset(1, 0, serialData.length, serialData[0].length)
    .setValues(serialData);
}
```

- Copy this into the script editor of the sheet
- Ensure the names of the sheet are correct! (This script assumes both are in the same file)
- Make sure the formats are the same as in the images.
- Run the script!

#### Explanation

This script first defines all the sheets and ranges that it has to use. It gets all the data with `getDataRange` which returns 2D arrays `serialData` and `orderData`. These arrays are updated within the script. It removes the header rows because `getDataRange` returns all the data. Then comes the main part of the script:

- For each line in the orders

  - It checks if it already has a serial number assigned
  - If it does, then it starts to go through all the laptops in `serials`
  - Once it finds a laptop that is both `DISPONIBLE` and that the model matches the order.
  - It updates the 2D arrays `serialData` and `orderData`. Changing `DISPONIBLE` to `ASIGNADO` in serials and adding the serial in the orders.
- Finally, it updates the ranges in the sheet with the new values.

#### References

- [Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Sheets Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)